# Loading types from .NET executables

Tags: .net, reflection

Is there any implications of loading types dynamically from a .NET assembly that is executable (.exe) compared to loading types from an .NET assembly compiled into a .dll?

What is the best and quickest way to test .exe and .dll if it is a .NET executable or 
not (just not a big fan of the BadImageFormatException)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

EXE and DLL files aren't much different in Windows, and even less so in .NET. It's essentially just a matter of what the entry point is and a few other details. (.NET DLLs do have an entry point, but you don't implement it. In native code it's called DllMain.)

As for testing if it's a .NET assembly, I'd recommend simply trying to load it for reflection-only and catching the exception. But if you really truly want to avoid that, check out [this blog entry](https://web.archive.org/web/20200219014454/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/rupreet/archive/2005/11/02/58873.aspx).

Comment: Yep. In my experience, the CLR doesn't see any difference between them; they are both assemblies full of types that can be referenced.

Answer (score 2):

There is one important consideration of using an exe to host types... it isn't very well supported by VS2005. The compiler (csc), runtime, etc all see no real problems - simply that the IDE isn't very happy about adding references to exe files.

This is fixed in VS2008, but if you need to support VS2005 developers, I would recommend using a dll for the reference.

At the assembly level, there isn't a huge amount of difference.

For distinguishing between the two (exe/dll) - check for an entry-point on the assembly:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Net;

class Program {
    static void Main() {
        IsItAnExe(typeof(Program).Assembly); // this one ;-p
        IsItAnExe(typeof(string).Assembly); // mscorlib
        IsItAnExe(typeof(WebClient).Assembly); // System
    }
    static void IsItAnExe(Assembly assembly) {
        MethodInfo entryPoint = assembly.EntryPoint;
        Console.WriteLine(assembly.GetName().Name + ": " +
            (entryPoint == null ? "no entry-point" :
            (entryPoint.DeclaringType.FullName + "." + entryPoint.Name)));
    }
}
```